# Is it possible to force a WebControl to render as a <div> instead of a <span>?

Tags: asp.net, html, .net-3.5, custom-server-controls

How can I force the `WebControl` to render as a `<div>`? Currently, it renders as a `<span>` and our UI guy prefers it be a `<div>`. To accommodate him, I'd like to see if this is possible and if so, how it's possible.

Comment: If it is your control, why can't you simply change it?

Comment: No need to be a smartass, @Trekstuff...I'm new to web development, so I don't always know exactly WHAT to ask or HOW to ask it.

Comment: This is more of a workaround rather than a solution, but why not style the `span` to behave like a `div`? The only major difference I'm aware of is that `span` is by default an inline element. I don't see much difference in web semantics either, or else your UI guy would be asking for `section` instead of `div`.

Comment: @Zhihao We would have if this would have been an arduous task, due to timelines, but it's really easy thanks to nunespascal. So it's better to do it right than to hack it. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible. Asp.net gives you full control over the output rendered.

Take a look at [Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx)

The asp.net team has released many adapters for CSS friendly rendering for controls like Menu, TreeView, and FormView. Take a look at [CSS friend control adapters](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/)

You can always build your own to customize the rendering as needed by your UI guy.

Answer (score 7):

You can override the RenderBeginTag method of WebControl:

```
public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.RenderBeginTag("div");
}
```

There's also a RenderEndTag that you can override, which might not be necessary in this case:

```
public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.RenderBeginTag();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably better to override `TagKey` like so:

`protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey => HtmlTextWriterTag.Div;`

Then any attributes the `WebControl` would render continue to be placed on opening tag.